# Find the Domain of the function: $f(x) = \frac{x^2+2x+3 }{ x^2 -9}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My answer is all reals for the numerator and  $(-∞, -3) \cup (-3, +3) \cup (3,∞)$.

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct, note that you may also write $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{-3,3\}$.

Comment: Here's a follow-up exercise: What is the domain of $\dfrac{x^2+2x-3}{x^2-9}$ ? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct. Since the denominator shouldn't be $0$ we don't want that $0=x^2-9 = (x-3)(x+3)$, i.e. $x= \pm 3$. By the way, note that 
$$ (-\infty,3) \cup (-3,3) \cup (3,\infty) = \mathbb{R}\setminus \{-3,3\}$$.